# Python Text Game : Program improvement

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code, which works. but I am struck with list dependency
which starts indexing with 0. That is,

When user Chooses, 1 it takes 0th element 
When user Chooses, 2 it takes 1st element
When user Chooses, 3 it takes 2nd element.. I t goes on like this.

I wants to overcome this, but not with any hack like internally converting the given text=text-1. please help. with any other solution

```
import numpy as np
Ran=[np.random.randint(1,5)]
Val=Ran[0]
print(Val)
#Items
items=['1. pot plant','2. painting','3. vase','4. lampshade','5. shoe']
print ("\n")
#Intro Text
print ("Last night you went to sleep in the comfort of your own home.")
print ("Now, you find yourself locked in a room. You don't know how")
print ("you got there or what time it is. In the room you can see")
print ("\n")
print (len(items), "Things:")
for x in items:
    print (x)
print ("")
print ("The door is locked. Could there be a key somewhere?")
print ("Enter the corresponding number of thing which you \
would like to check..Yougot only 3 chances !! ")
k=0
while (k==0):
    Ins1 = int(input())
    if (Ins1 == Val):
        print("You're Lucky! Got the key in First instance ")
        break
    else:
        c=items[Ins1]
        print("Damn ! key is not available in ", c , "Try again..")
    Ins2 = int(input())
    if (Ins2 == Val):
        print("Got the key on your 2nd attempt")
        break
    else:
        c=items[Ins2]
        print("Bad luck ! Try again..not in ", c ,"your last attempt")
    Ins3 = int(input())
    if (Ins3 == Val):
        print("Finally you got the key")
        break
    else:
        c=items[Ins3]
        print("you're done. Die here :( Key not in ",c,)
        break
```

Comment: Just put a dummy '' value at the beginning of `items`.

Comment: But the user will view the dummy value, as am printing the options to him.

Comment: Just start at 1 then: `for x in items[1:]: print(x)`

Comment: Thanks Paul ! It works Fine :)

Comment: Paul, can you suggest a way for intending python code, as i am using notepad editor, frequently getting “inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation” error.

Comment: A nice no-frills editor for Windows is wscite. But lately I've also tried thonny, which you can install like any Python module using pip. Both will help you do auto indenting, and thonny can also help you with autocomplete

Answer (score 0):

> Resolved in comments:
>
> ```
> Just put a dummy '' value at the beginning of items. – Paul McGuire  
>
> But the user will view the dummy value, as am printing the options to him. – Abdul Salam  
>
> Just start at 1 then: for x in items[1:]: print(x) – Paul McGuire
>
> Thanks Paul ! It works Fine :)
> ```